# Java Jackson writeAsString conversion

Tags: java-8, jackson

using Java8 with jackson

I have code convert A class into json String, which works fine, i have Scenario where if i want values of rate1 and rate2 to be blank string if certain values.

I am wondering if there is quick and easy way to do it ?

```
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisiblity=ANY)
    class A{

    UUID id;
    CustomEnumType type;
    BigDecimal value;
    BigDecimal rate1
    BigDecimal rate2;
    }

A a = new A();
// a filled up with values
string jsonStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a);
```

I tried using custom Seralizer class as following but not sure how do i convert UUID string representation ?

```
public class ASerializer extends StdSerializer<A>{

... ASerializer()..

@Override
public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider p){
  g.writeStratObject();
  // how do i convert UUID to string ? 

  g.writeEndObject();


   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `toString`, UUID has static  `fromString` method to deserialize.

Comment: that works but i feel like to change rate1 and rate2 values i had to write code to produce custom json. in future if we add any field i have to add in seralizer too :(

Comment: You can have serialiser/deserialiser annotation applied on fields, then you can customize only the field you need and not the whole class